# Setup.py not including bs4.py

Tags: python, html-parsing, executable, os.walk, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create a .exe using py2exe. I am using python 2.17.10. My setup.py is as follows:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import bs4, py2exe, HTMLParser

setup(
    console=["Report.py"],
    zipfile = None,
    author='author',
    py_modules =['bs4', 'HTMLParser'],
    options = {"py2exe":{"packages":"encodings",
                     "includes":["HTMLParser", "bs4"],
                     "bundle_files":2,
                     "optimize":2},},
)
```

Unfortunately, running `python setup.py install` doesn't find bs4.py. Given below is the screenshot:

[image]

The `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` does not contain a script bs4.py.

Neither `BeautifulSoup`:

[image]

My query is whether it is a requirement to have bs4 as module stated in the setup.py file.

My script imports the following modules:

```
import HTMLParser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag, NavigableString
from os import walk
```

Running my Report.py file gives me the desired result, but after generating the .exe and running it, don't the see the expected results. So, not sure where I might be going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. My main problem was with the implementation of py2exe with bs4. I had a line of code:

```html
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("C:/Users/My_PC/Desktop/output/{}".format(report)), 'lxml')
```

The `lxml` parser wasn't working for me when the script was converted to an exe with py2exe. I replaced it with `html.parser`. Worked for me.